# extract specific rows from csv file in java

Tags: java, csv

I have a huge csv file. One of the column's name is "years" having entries from 1900 to 2010. I want to fetch rows having 1990 and 2000 column entries only in java.

Comment: Use query according to your Database using condition of "1990 to 2010". For e.g, SELECT years
FROM table_name
WHERE year BETWEEN 1990 AND 2000;

Comment: Can you show what you've done so far?

Comment: @Tehmina...the data is already sorted according to years

Comment: There are a plenty of ways to do it. Like simply read the file line by line and split each row by separator, and then find appropriate column and value in it. What exactly you can't achieve, what issues do you have? [Here](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/) you can find several different approaches

Comment: @Totò Till now I am reading the whole csv file using BufferedReader.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a csv parser like openCsv, superCsv .... Using openCsv your code can look like something like this:

```
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Elvis {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"));
        String [] nextLine;
        int columnIndexOfYears = 1;
        while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            if(nextLine[columnIndexOfYears].matches("1999|2000")){
                System.out.println(nextLine[0] + nextLine[1] + "etc...");
            }               
        } 
    }        
 }
```